# Error messages does not print in blade laravel 5.2

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm working on Laravel 5.2, where I've this form with some fields. on submit I'm checking the values aganist few rules. I'm getting the validation message in its callback when I do

> print_r($messages); die;

in controller.

But it is not showing the error messages in the blade.

It is working well and good in my localhost, but the server I've hosted it to is a bluemix server. which does nto show the error message at all. I've tried to debug there also. I've got error messages in controller. but not showing it on view.

```
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), static::$rules, static::$messages);
        $validator->setAttributeNames(static::$names);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $messages = $validator->messages();
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($messages);
        }
```

In view I'm printing it as

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" value="{{ old('FirstName') }}">
<div class="error">{{ $errors->first('FirstName') }}</div>
```

Comment: instead of print_r($messages); die; you could use dd($messages) in laravel.

Comment: What if you use `->get('FirstName')` instead of `->first`?

Comment: @Marwelln htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /home/vcap/app/htdocs/resources/views/user/register.blade.php) I've got this

Comment: Isnt problem that in documentation is, that you should pass in withErrors the $validator object and no $messages?

Comment: @Autista_z I've passsed that also, but no luck.

Comment: If you make in your *view* `<?php dd($errors); ?>` Do you have the error object/array?

Comment: @Autista_z ViewErrorBag {#167 ▼
  #bags: []
}
 this is what I get

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting with errors just flashes the validation error messages to the session. Looks like your errors not getting flashed. I'm guessing you're not using the `web` middleware group. You need to place your routes within the `web` middleware group for sessions to work.

Example

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

**Edit**

You could also simplify your code like so.

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), static::$rules, static::$messages, static::$names);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    // handle success
}
```

Or

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, static::$rules, static::$messages, static::$names);

    // handle success
}
```

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra can you run `php artisan route:list` and post the result? Also mention the route which displays the form.

Comment: It is working well in my localhost, the issue is in my bluemix server. and there they don' provide ssh control.

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra can you try {{ var_dump($errors) }} from your view and see what the values are on validation error.

Comment: Session it is working I can print the session variable. var dump is an empty error. Is it an issue with bluemix server?

Comment: Add the var_dump n see what the `$errors` contains on failed validation

Comment: I think on page refresh the error array is getting reset. What do you think could it be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145701/discussion-between-sandeesh-and-fazeela-abu-zohra).

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra join the chat for a moment